# How to show progress in a job in eclipse rcp?

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, rcp, progress

I update the gui of my eclipse rcp application with asyncExec() in the run()-method of a job.

```
Job job = new Job("The Job") {

        @Override
        protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
            try {
                monitor.beginTask("", IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN);

                Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        \\update gui
                    }
                });
...
 PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getProgressService().showInDialog(Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell(), job);
    job.schedule();
```

I am trying to show the user some indication of how long it is going to take with a progress monitor and the showInDialog method but i would also like to have a busy cursor in the first few moments before the dialog appears. How does it work in this case with the BusyIndicator? I also have the problem that i can't cancel or exit the progress dialog (cancel button and exit button don't show any effect).

Answer (score 1):

`Job` is not suitable for passing to the progress service like this.

You should just call `job.schedule()` and let it run. If you call

```
job.setUser(true);
```

before scheduling the job it will display a progress dialog of its own after a few seconds.

Your job should call `monitor.worked(1)` regularly to update the progress monitor. The job should call `monitor.isCanceled()` to check for the cancel button.

If your job is mostly doing GUI work then use `UIJob` to run the whole job in the UI thread (but this is more likely to slow down the UI).

Comment: ah i did try that too sorry but the cancel button still doesn't work. I called monitor.isCanceled() to check for it but nothing happens.  monitor.beginTask("", IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN);
                    
                    if (monitor.isCanceled()) {
                        System.out.println("hello");
                    }